# Weird glitched material

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Honestly, I don't know what this is anymore, I have never seen anything like this before. It is not a UV map issue (this object doesn't even use UV, only basic color).
[image]

Anyway, I have tried to recalculate normals, tried to UV unwrap it, just in case, changed materials and I don't know what more... Odd thing is that this only happens in Cycles, not Eevee:
This is in Eevee
[image]

Also, it is bad only from this one side. The other side is fine:
[image]

Does somebody know what else could cause this? And why is it only visible on one side of the object?

File:
[image]

Comment: Are you using an AMD GPU?

Comment: FWIW it looks fine in Cycles with my NVIDIA/I7/Windows 10/2.93.5 setup.  I'm guessing GPU.

Comment: Hi everyone, after a short while, I discovered that I forgot one thing, origin... I realized that the origin point is for some reason way too far away in the deformed normals... So I set the origin point in the middle of the mass and it was solved... didn't know that the origin point can cause something like that